# DirectX Rendering & OMP

Tags: c++, rendering, directx-11, openmp

I want to make my code parallel, but have some questions for the experienced.

**1] Is it a good idea to do something like this?**

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
{
    const int threadID=omp_get_thread_num();
    if(threadID==0) while(WM_QUIT != msg.message){ // < Engine stuff
        if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)){
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }else{
            engine.omp_renderPrepare();
        }
    }
    if(threadID==1) while(WM_QUIT != msg.message){ // < Render stuff
        engine.omp_renderApply();
    }
}

// Functions from the engine class:
inline void omp_renderPrepare(){
    if(gDevice.omp_isReady()){
#pragma omp critical(renderPrepare)
        if(!omp_rendering){
            omp_sceneReady=0;
            renderPrepare();
            omp_sceneReady=1;
        }
    }else{
        Sleep(42); // If the device is not ready, dont spam.
    }
}
inline void omp_renderApply(){
    if(gDevice.omp_isReady()){
#pragma omp critical(omp_renderApply)
        if(omp_sceneReady){
            omp_rendering=1;
            renderApply();
            omp_rendering=0;
        }
    }else{
        Sleep(42); // If the device is not ready, dont spam.
    }
}
```

I already applied it, but it is heavy on the CPU & my code slows to a crawl when I resize the window, since it must:

1. Set a bool "omp_deviceReady" to false so the rendering will stop.
2. Wait for the parallel sections to stop.
3. Resizing the graphics buffers.
4. Set "omp_deviceReady" to true so rendering can happen again.
5. Repeat as long as the user resizes the window.

**2]** Since my OMP code is heavy on the CPU [about 50% accord to task mgr], **what is a good way to handle parallel rendering?**

Comment: From my coding experience, looks like preparing the buffers & presenting the buffers separately is not a good idea.  I should look up using multiple swap chains instead.

Comment: What version of DirectX are you using? multi threaded rendering techniques can vary greatly depending on API version.

Comment: Ohh, I am using DX 10/11

Comment: OMP isn't too well suited for MT rendering (OMP would work better for parallel processing of game tasks). under DX11 you would use deffered contexts, the DXSDK has a sample of this, but it isn't too great, Dice's BF3 presentations give much better tips and pointers, and this older MS presentation should help: http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=14886

Comment: @RandomClown i agree with Necrolis, i would look at BF3's presentations (they are a must read, link here : http://www.slideshare.net/DICEStudio/directx-11-rendering-in-battlefield-3?from=ss_embed). Deffered contexts is a good way to go, but become useful when you start to have a lot of draw calls. I would also look at the resource streaming  section (great for parallel resource loading), and mostly the instancing part (which is imo where you can get your greatest gains).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"OMP isn't too well suited for MT rendering (OMP would work better for parallel processing of game tasks)" – Necrolis

"Deffered contexts is a good way to go, ..." – catflier